# How to swap values of rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val result = df
               .groupBy("col1")
               .agg(min('minTimestamp) as "StartDateUTC", 
                    max('maxTimestamp) as "EndDateUTC")
```

For each `col1` I should find the minimum and maximum timestamps. The problem is that in some cases `StartDateUTC` is greater than `EndDateUTC` (see the case `A` in `df`). Is there any efficient way to swap these values in such cases?

```
df =

col1    minTimestamp    maxTimestamp
A       1483264800      1483164800
A       1483200000      1483064800
B       1483300000      1483564800
```

Comment: use when/otherwise with withColumn for swapping the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`least` / `greatest`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(
    $"col1", 
    least($"minTimestamp", $"maxTimestamp").alias("minTimestamp"),
    greatest($"minTimestamp", $"maxTimestamp").alias("maxTimestamp")
)
```

or pushed into aggregation

```
.agg(
  min(least($"minTimestamp", $"maxTimestamp")) as "StartDateUTC", 
  max(greatest($"minTimestamp", $"maxTimestamp")) as "EndDateUTC"
)
```

Comment: Why cannot I do `max('maxTimestamp, 'minTimestamp)`? What is the reason of using `least` and `greatest`?